# gnome apps very slow to start on on remote X server, other apps ok

Tags: gnome, remote, x-server, delay, mobaxterm

I'm using [meld](https://meldmerge.org) to compare some files, on a machine running SLES 15 SP 1, and with the X server running on a Windows desktop; it's [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)'s embedded X server, which I believe is Cygwin'ish.

For some reason, meld takes ~30 seconds create its window on the X server - even if no files are being compared and it's just the empty window. The same is true for `gedit`, for example. However, for apps like `xclock`, `xterm` or even say `kile` - the delay is very small - less than half a second.

After coming up, the apps are pretty responsive, and this is all on a LAN, so it's not as though it's a communications problem (I'm pretty sure anyway).

What could cause such delays, and what can I do to avoid or at least mitigate them?

Naturally, I'll provide any additional information which might be useful to figure this out.

Comment: is it every single application, or does `meld` start quickly if `gedit` is already running?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Always starts slow, even if another instance of itself is already running.